Create a Windows Installer for .NET WPF app
I've already created a Wpf application on .NET8.0 and now I want to create a Windows installer with it.
I want the Windows installer to be a standalone application without having to install .NET dependencies after the application is installed. To create the installer I used WiX toolset (The latest version). The problem is:
The windows installer doesn't offer to install the .exe but only the .dll which isn't an executable by the way. I used the WiX Setup Editor to edit the installer file more easily, except that I can't find any .exe or .config file in the files to be installed.
In the app properties, I have the output type set to Windows Application.
I've been at it for about 2 days without finding anything.
Thank you in advance.
If you need more info, don't hesitate.
I have tried to add manually the .exe but the app after install don't work. Just do nothing.
After fiew try,
The solution is to use the Visual Studio installer for Net8.0 solutions as WiX toolset doesn't seem to be adapted to recent apps (I think). So I've managed to create the installer, but now I've got a second problem: the installation is done in x64 ProgramFiles, so I can only run the application as an admin, and my application doesn't react at all when I run it like any other app on my PC. It's problematic if only for the convenience of users to avoid clicking yes for admin permissions at every launch.
Do you have a solution? If you need any info, don't hesitate! Thank you in advance.
